# Pulling info from an api

Tags: javascript, php, api

I am trying to pull info from this api http://www.ticketfly.com/api/events/upcoming.rss?orgId=333
and I am not sure how to do this. This is something I really want to learn so I don't what to just hire someone to do it. I have some knowledge in JS and PHP. I am constantly trying to learn more. Does anyone know a good resource that can show my how to do this? I am basically trying to get this to show the listing of shows like it is here [http://www.thesatellitela.com/listing/](http://www.thesatellitela.com/listing) . I have been trying to google it and also checked this site but I have not found anything yet. Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks
Jeff

Comment: Do they not have any documentation on their site?

Comment: could be as simple as `file_get_contents('URL');`

Comment: They do and I have read through it but I am having trouble just figuring out how to get it up on the page. What language to use? Do I use php, Js, I just don't know where to get started.

Comment: http://start.ticketfly.com/api/ have you applied for a key?

Comment: current url show you just want to scrape an rss feed. its not really part of the api. http://start.ticketfly.com/api-example/

Comment: Is that what I am trying to do here? Scrape an rss feed? That is the address ticketfly gave me to get my schedule up on to our wordpress site. Now I am just trying to figure out a way to get that info to show up on our site. Once I get it to show I can style it with css. I am just having trouble trying to figure out how to get it to show in the first place.

Comment: did you try file_get_contents it will get the contents of the url then you hve to pares the rss feed,

Answer (score -1):

We see you dont realy try to use the api, you just try to get the content from an rss feed like @Dagon allready sayed.

So my recommandation is to look for a easy and usable rss reader class, find some that is helpfull for your usage. The most rss reader classes handle the things easy and you get an array that contain the title and the content of a post, sometimes with additional informations like date and timestamps, depends on the used rss reader class and the rss feed itself.